# Change Runlevel In CentOS 7 with SystemD

Tags: centos, systemd

In CentOS 7 I wanted to start httpd service only in runlevel 3 and 5, in other runlevels such as 2 and 4 the service shouldn't start.

In CentOS 6 we can achieve this by using "chkconfig" command. Looking for similar solution in CentOS 7 environment.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. But how to force httpd to run only on runlevel 3 and 5. What I am looking is when I switch runlevel to 2 the httpd service should stop.

Comment: @user358804 RHEL7 is based on systemd. systemd doesn't really have a concept of runlevels (it has targets which are sort of a superset of the functionality provided by runlevels). so your question of "how do I force httpd to run only on such-and-such runlevels under systemd" is somewhat nonsensical. you really should read that question; it was linked for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have mentioned that you would like to start HTTPD in runlevel 3 and 5, and to stop HTTPD in runlevel 2 and 4. Here is a URL to the Red Hat manual the provides a great overview of Init and SystemD.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Targets.html

The Red Hat manual states that multi-user.target is the same as runlevels 2, 3, and 4.

- Runlevel 0 = poweroff.target
- Runlevel 1 = rescue.target
- Runlevel 2 = multi-user.target
- Runlevel 3 = multi-user.target
- Runlevel 4 = multi-user.target
- Runlevel 5 = graphical.target
- Runlevel 6 = reboot.target

With this in mind, it seems like there would be no point in using a command such as `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` in an attempt to switch between runlevels 2, 3, and 4, since runlevels 2, 3, and 4 are synonymous with multi-user.target.

It is noteworthy that the `systemctl cat httpd` command can be used to view some of the configuration information. Related to your question, this command will show that HTTPD is set to multi-user.target.

```
# systemctl cat httpd
. . .
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am not sure if this would be appropriate for your environment. A possible solution to your need may be to have a script that determines the current run-level of the system, and then uses some if loops to start or stop the HTTPD daemon based on the target. For example, perhaps the script could look a little something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
target=`systemctl get-default`
if [ $target == "multi-user.target" ]
then
  systemctl stop httpd
else
  systemctl start httpd
fi
```